# Error deserializing xml web response

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I am trying to deserialize a "SearchRecordList" class using the DataContractSerializer and keep getting the exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No corresponding start element is open.
```

The XML i am receiving looks like this:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><records type=\"array\" count=\"0\"/>
```

What is strange, is that if i run a test, and pass this XML string:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><records type=\"array\" count=\"0\"></records>
```

It works fine.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?  Below is the class I am deserializing to (C#, .NET 4.0):

```
 [XmlRoot(Namespace = "", ElementName = "records", DataType = "array")]
public class SearchRecordList:List<SearchRecord>, IXmlSerializable
{

    #region IXmlSerializable Members

    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        var navigator = reader.CreateNavigator(); //returns an XPathNavigator based on the reader.
        var root = navigator.SelectSingleNode("records");

        int count;

        if (!int.TryParse(root.GetAttribute("count", ""), out count) || count < 1)
            return;

        navigator.MoveToFirstChild();

        var n = navigator.Select("record");

        AddRange(n.ToList<SearchRecord>());
    }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried testing it using the /> like the received xml is, instead of closing with </records>? I have no clue if that will help, but I've had some things be picky about that for some reason.

Comment: Ya, ive passed both of the noted strings, the first one that is self closing errors out with the same exception, the second one passes.

Comment: The DataContractSerializer is not directly related to IXmlSerializable. Why are you using IXmlSerializable?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I just realized that you said that in your question and I misread it. Your code looks fine; I'm pretty sure that it's just the XPathNavigator being picky about that tag closing. I don't have a way off the top of my head to fix that though... I'll poke around a little.

Comment: @John Saunders:  IXmlSerializable is used to control the deserialization, otherwise DataContractSerializer uses its default mechanisms and adds namespaces and looks for ArrayOfSearchRecords, rathan than "records" element.

Comment: Then why even bother using the Data Contract Serializer. You're not, really - you're actually using the XML Serializer.

Comment: This post has some good insights on XmlSerializer vs. DataContractSerializer ( http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/03/07/xmlserializer-vs-datacontractserializer-serialization-in-wcf/). One of the disadvantages the author lists for DataContractSerializer is that you don't have much control over the serialized output. I feel like that is the problem you are running into here.

Comment: I dont control the output/response at all.  Really the only reason I used the DataContractSerializer is because it makes casting easier.  My ReadXml implimentation doesnt work for XmlSerializer (im referring to the n.ToList<T>() i do).  How could I translate that to work with the XmlSerializer?

Comment: Id love pointers guys!  TBH, Im used to working with WCF and havent worked with a POX service in years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the `DataContractSerializer` should only be used to deserialize data that was serialized using the `DataContractSerializer`. It's just not as flexible as something like `XmlSerializer`.  For example, the `DataContractSerializer` expects all XML elements to be in alphabetical order when it deserializes (see the accepted answer here: [WCF web service Data Members defaulting to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737552/wcf-web-service-data-members-defaulting-to-null)). How can you guarantee that the web service you are calling is going to adhere to this requirement? To put it another way, the `DataContractSerializer` is not a general purpose XML deserializer, it expects data in a very specific format. To the `DataContractSerializer`, `<records></records>` and `<records />` are not equivalent.

If the data you are consuming is coming from a web service, you probably should just call the web service by setting up a Service Reference. If you don't want to do that, then I would use `XmlSerializer`. It doesn't sound like `DataContractSerializer` is the right class to use in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

If XPath is giving you trouble you could use LINQ to XML instead. Since LINQ is not a forward-only parser, it can parse the document with out needing to know too much about its structure. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx